# Can we do Post and Delete with one endpoint in Web API

Tags: c#, rest

I have a button which on click need to delete some selected records, and add the deselected records, How I can accommodate this in one endpoint of Web API.

Comment: The WebApi function can do anything you want it to do, what is your problem here?

Comment: What approach you will have for that. Will this be restful.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate endpoints as these are two separate methods.  Send one request to the DELETE endpoint and then another request to a different POST endpoint to create the deselected records.  You should keep the separate operations apart.

Comment: So you mean it wrong to do both operation in one endpoint, then I have one more question I have multiple records to be deleted, but I cannot send body for Delete, If I use Comma separated value in url, is that approach a correct way to do this, or do we have any other way to do this.

Comment: You could send it as a comma separated value (ensuring that it will still work if you send a single ID), or have a delete method that uses POST if you wish to send the ID's in the body.  If you're using the default WebAPI routing where it uses the method names to determine the HTTP verbs then this may become problematic if you already have a POST on your controller.  If you choose to use the second option, I'd recommend looking into Attribute Routing - you're not restricted to only having one POST, one DELETE and so on.